# How to draw and index "trial plots"

Tags: qgis-3, grids-graticules, indexing

I've starting using QGIS to extract data from drone survey maps of agricultural field trials. One of my biggest hurdles is actually drawing the polygons and identifying them in a way that I can analyze the data.

I tried drawing a polygon manually and then copying and moving it multiple times until I have the whole area covered. This works well but they all share the same ID. Then if I try to update them all using something like @row_number, the numbering is fairly random and impossible to sort.

I've also tried using the "Create Grid" tool but I need gaps between the plots to account for tractor wheeling's. I can use the "Buffer" tool but I need a bigger gap at the tops and bottoms than I do for the sides and this doesn't seem to be possible.

I've tried using a plugin called "Plot Boundary" which seems to have been designed for this purpose but I can't get it to work.

The closest I can get is by using the "Create Grid" tool to create a single row, then copying and moving it, and then applying the buffer. Then gives me the following output..

[image]

But, as you can see, in this case the numbering is still hasn't worked in the order I want. It doesn't appear to have realized that it needs to start on the bottom row.

Ideally I also need the grid to be indexed in the attribute table with a column number and a row number as it makes it a lot easier to sort the data and append it to other data sets. But I can get by for now as long as the ID numbers is in the correct order.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can also try the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) and playing a bit with a *'Sorting expression [optional]'*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Grid, point type
   [image]
2. Rectangles, ovals, diamonds. Create rectangles smaller than the grid spacing
   [image]
3. Add a field new id field, adjust first two lines and execute this in python console:

   ```
   layername = 'Polygon' #Change to your layername
   idfield = 'newid' #Change to match the name of your field

   layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]
   coords = [[round(f.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(),0),round(f.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(),0),f.id()] for f in layer.getFeatures()]
   coords.sort(key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]))
   order = [i[2] for i in coords]

   i = layer.fields().indexFromName(idfield)
   attrMap = {id: {i:e} for e,id in enumerate(order,1)}
   layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
   ```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it crashes when I run the python code but this is an excellent way of drawing the plots! Thank you! :D

Comment: Ok nice that at least parts of it works :). I cant debug the code without your data

Answer (score 2):

**The solution**

You can use a QGIS expression to number the polygons from `1` to `N` with a simple (well - a single, even if scary looking, but rather easy) expression that creates a new attribute with field calculator. See below for the expression.

**Explanation**

The expression is based on the x and y-coordinate values of the centroid of each polygon and evaluates the sequence: from top left to the right, then down to the next line etc. The polygon with the smallest x-value **and** the highest y-value (= the upper left polygon) gets the value of 1, the next to it's right is no. 2 and so forth. When a line ends, it goes to the next row and continues numbering. That's all (basically).

**Options**

Varying distances between the polygons, different size and other irregularities play not role as long as the centroids of the polygons are in the correct order: left to right, than top to bottom. Adding a `round()` statement, you could even use it if the centroids would not be exactly on a line.

**The expression to create a new attribute**

```
array_find (
    array_sort( 
        array_agg ( 
            array_find( 
                array_sort (
                    array_agg(  
                        x ($geometry), 
                        order_by:= y($geometry)
                    )
                ),
                x ($geometry)
            )
            +
            array_find( 
                array_sort (
                    array_agg(  
                        y ($geometry), 
                        order_by:= x($geometry)
                    ),
                    false
                ),
                y ($geometry)
            )*100
        )
    ), 
    array_find( 
        array_sort (
            array_agg(  
                x ($geometry), 
                order_by:= y($geometry)
            )
        ),
        x ($geometry)
    )
    +
    array_find( 
        array_sort (
            array_agg(  
                y ($geometry), 
                order_by:= x($geometry)
            ),
            false
        ),
        y ($geometry)
    )*100
)+1
```

**Screenshot**

*For demonstration purpose, here I inserted the expression to create a label from it:*

[image]